# What's the coalescing width in recent NVIDIA GPUs?

Tags: memory, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

In [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5213922&tag=1) the authors say that CUDA's coalescing width on NVIDIA GPUs at that time was 16 (page 3, last paragraph). This paper is quite old and I couldn't find this information for newer devices.

What is the coalescing width for recent NVIDIA GPUs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 32-bit quantities, the cc1.x GPUs of that era would break a warp into two "half-warps" (1), and issue a global transaction for each half-warp.  The warp was still 32 threads, but a half warp was 16 threads, which I presume is where that 16 number is coming from.

[Modern GPUs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-2-x) (cc2.x - cc5.x) issue global transactions at full warp width, which is 32 (threads).  If the quantity requested per thread is larger than 32-bits, this will be broken into multiple 128-byte transactions, as many as are required to service the warp.

Therefore I would say the corresponding number is 32, but it will depend on the actual data requested per thread.

Whether and how data actually coalesces is a function of the addresses (generated by the individual threads) that comprise a warp transaction, in addition to just the "width".

(1): online documentation for cc1.x devices is not as conveniently available, but excerpting from the programming guide for CUDA 5.0 for cc1.x:

> F.3.2 Global Memory
>   A global memory request for a warp is split into two memory requests, one for each halfwarp,
>   that are issued independently. Devices of Compute Capability 1.0 and 1.1 and
>   Devices of Compute Capability 1.2 and 1.3 describe how the memory accesses of threads
>   within a half-warp are coalesced into one or more memory transactions depending on the
>   compute capability of the device.